# How to compute the value of n+nn+nnn+nnnn with a given digit as the value of n

Tags: python

Write a program that computes the value of n+nn+nnn+nnnn with a given digit as the value of n.
For example, if n=9 , then you have to find the value of 9+99+999+9999

I need some pointers to make this code dynamic in nature.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: how about `print(sum([int(n * i) for i in range(1, int(n)+1)]))`

Comment: Wait is the number of n +nn +nnn......to be dynamic, or is it always n + nn + nnn + nnnn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

taking into account *`k`* terms and a value *`n`* :

```
(10**np.arange(k)).cumsum().sum()*n
```

**Example**

```
k=4
n=1
(10**np.arange(k)).cumsum().sum()*n
#1234
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that parameters are:

- *k* - the number of numbers to sum (e.g. in the title of your post
  there are **4** numbers to sum),
- *n* - the digit with increasing number number of occurrences in each
  number to sum.

Then the function counting such a sum can be expressed as:

```
def mySum(k, n):
    return n * sum([ n1 * n2 for n1, n2 in zip(
        [ i + 1 for i in range(k) ],
        [ 10 ** (k - i - 1) for i in range(k) ])])
```

E.g. `mySum(4, 2)` gives *2468* (*2* + *22* + *222* + *2222*).

**Details of the above case**

If *k == 4*, but *n == 1*, we can break the sum into:

```
   1  =                                1
  11  =                       10     + 1
 111  =             100     + 10     + 1
1111  =  1000     + 100     + 10     + 1
---------------------------------------------
1234 =   1000 * 1 + 100 * 2 + 10 * 3 + 1 * 4
```

Note that:

- `[ i + 1 for i in range(k) ]` yields *[1, 2, 3, 4]*,
- `[ 10 ** (k - i - 1) for i in range(k) ]` yields *[1000, 100, 10, 1]*,

so multiplication of these 2 zipped lists yields *[1000, 200, 30, 4]*
and sum of it is *1234*.

Now, if *n* is e.g. *2*, all that remains to be done is to multiply the
abobe sum just by *n* and this is the result.

Comment: If *n == 2* then the result is *2 \* 1234*, and so on (up to *9*). So, having *n* it is enough to perform a **single** multiplication. Check for all 10 possible results (*n* from *0* to *9*).

Comment: I think this should be extrapolated for k terms

Comment: The post states that there are just 4 values.

Comment: OP said: *I need some pointers to make this code dynamic in nature* ,
although it is true that dynamic can mean many things:)

Answer (score 0):

Can try this out. Modify the range of loop as per program.

```
num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
t = 0
total = 0

for a in range(4):
    t  = num + t*10
    total = total + t
     
print(total)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
number = int(input("number"))
print(number * 100 + number * 10 + number + number * 10 + number + number)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I do not see how this answers the question at the top of this page, but it should. Please [edit] according to [answer] or delete the answer. Otherwise it risks being flagged as "not an answer" and being deleted. Make clear how this answers to the explicit aspect of a dynamic program.